# Variant array with string in first index - overwrite that with double - type mismatch

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a variant array that looks like this:

"dog"
"cat"
"horse"

I want to overwrite those values with

```
1.01
2.02
3.03
```

Code:

```
sumHolder = loanSums(x)
If sumHolder = "N/A" Then
    sumHolder = "0"
End If
loanSums(x) = vbNull
loanSums(x) = sumHolder + trimmedRange(i, trimmedRngCols.paymentAmt)
```

I have tried to just assign the double over the string and I get a type mismatch.  Any thoughts on how to do this

Comment: Show your code.  Hard to find a problem if there's nothing to look at.

Comment: fill them with string instead: `"1.01", "2.02", "3.03"` then when pulling the "text" from the array turn them into numbers.

Comment: if the values are in variables then use CStr(varName), and then what Scott said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not doing it right.

One dimensional variant array:

```
Dim a As Long, vals As Variant

vals = Array("dog", "cat", "horse")

For a = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
    Debug.Print vals(a)
    vals(a) = CDbl(a + 1 + (a + 1) / 100)
Next a

For a = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
    Debug.Print vals(a)
Next a
```

Results from the Immediate window:

```
dog
cat
horse
 1.01 
 2.02 
 3.03
```

Two dimensioned variant array:

```
dim a as long, vals as variant, tmp as variant

vals = range("A2:E4").value2

debug.print lbound(vals, 1) & ":" & ubound(vals, 1)  '1:3, 3 'rows' in array
debug.print lbound(vals, 2) & ":" & ubound(vals, 2)  '1:5, 5 'columns' in array

for a = lbound(vals, 1) to ubound(vals, 1)
    debug.print vals(a, 1) & " - " & vals(a, 3)
    tmp = vals(a, 1)
    vals(a, 1) = vals(a, 3)
    vals(a, 3) = tmp
next a

for a = lbound(vals, 1) to ubound(vals, 1)
    debug.print vals(a, 1) & " - " & vals(a, 3)
next a

range("A2").resize(ubound(vals, 1), ubound(vals, 2)) = vals
```

Results from the Immediate window and worksheet:

```
1:3
1:5
dog - 1.01
cat - 2.02
horse - 3.03
1.01 - dog
2.02 - cat
3.03 - horse
```

[image: variant_array_substitution_before]    [image: variant_array_substitution_after]
                      <sup>before processing</sup>                                                  <sup>after processing</sup>

I've included some before-and-after images so that you can clearly see by the left-alignment (text) and right-alignment (numbers) of the cell values that swapping a variant number for text and vise-versa should not be an issue. Your *'type mis-match'* must be something other than value transfer.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for.